# How to bring an image inside a GUI? Its possible in BashScript or Let's learn a new language?

Tags: bash, image, user-interface

I am developing my first pretty application in Bashscript, hmm...

So.. I am starting some kind of GUI for it, with `zenity` on this first try. But I want to bring some visual art inside the GUI, with no function at all, just some visual art. **I want the final application to be cross-os executable.**

How to just show an image inside a GUI box? (Maybe with just a OK button, or nothing, just show the image for some time).

Any "easy" solution for this? In BashScript or whatever? Any solution, specially in C, or other languages, is highly appreciatted too...

Thanks for your attenttion, have a good day.

I found Glade with gtk, but have to deep in yet. Any other solution?

**EDIT**:

**I want the final application to be cross-os executable.**

Hey... Pretty road... I found [**a crazy guy like me**, he wants a GTK GUI with Bashscript!](http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,59050.0/wap2.html) I am not the only crazy dude in the world, lol....

And I want a "easy" solution, just because what I need for **my program is really simple,** GUI shows image, buttons, and done. Just to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `display` command in [`ImageMagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php):

```
$ display img.png
```

It will show the image in a GUI window.

Comment: Nice shot kev, I already did this. But I want to display a image to compose with my GUI, not just display a image. If I can change my title bar in this window (not "_IMagemagick doing something wrote on top_") and maybe add some buttons or an auto-close feature by time, then ImageMagick will won the trophy and your answer will be choosed as the right one for my problem. Many thanks for your contribution. (I just miss this 2 things with ImageMagick: 1- Control of the Title of the Window and 2- Some way to Close or Auto-Close the Window.) Why CamelCase? JustForFun. =D

Comment: some edit in my question, maybe you like to follow link to know this one.

Comment: @H_7 You can use `python tkinter` package

Answer (score 1):

Bash is not a language for writing GUI applications. There are extensions such as dialog, zenity, and others that allow for using a GUI or TUI to accept input for further bash processing, but these things are very limited. You need to pick a toolkit, such as GTK, QT, or wxWidgets. Most high level scripting languages will have bindings for all the GUI toolkits that I have proved examples for (python, ruby, perl).

Comment: some people is starting to think a bit different. http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,59050.0/wap2.html

Comment: You can also write games in sed, but that doesn't make it the right tool for the job.